# Adding attribute values to a join table record in a has_many :through association upon creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I am setting up a has_many :through relationship on my Rails 3.2 app. I have most everything working, except that I'm not sure how to add values to attributes on the join table when relationships are created.

Here are the models (notice the **source_id** on the **Checkins** table):

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "checkins", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "location_id"
  t.integer  "source_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "locations", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

Here's the relationship setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checkins
  has_many :locations, :through => :checkins
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checkins
  has_many :users, :through => :checkins
end

class Checkin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm using these instructions (in essence) to loadi a User and Location and create the relationship with a Checkin:

```
source_id = 10
@user = User.first
@location = Location.first
@user.locations << @location
```

So, my question is, how do I also add a **source_id** value to the **Checkins** table when using this line:

```
@user.locations << @location
```

I'm also open to suggestions on a better process for creating new User Checkins with this relationship than what I have above (I've seen the **create** and **build** methods used, but none seemed to work for me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a `Checkin` object directly.

```
checkin = Checkin.new user: @user, location: @location, source_id: source_id 
checkin.save
```

Comment: That works well. Can you perhaps direct me to a document that would detail this operation (or just basic CRUD) for a has_many :through association? The Rails Guide I found tells you how to set it up, but not really the CRUD methods to use.

Comment: @wrburgess did you ever find a resource that explains the CRUD for a has_many :through association?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association